# react-router: match and route. Replacement of .match() in v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4, server-side-rendering

How can I match and route in react-router v4?

Below is the code snippet I wrote using react-router(v2) and expressJs for server side rendering.

```
 var routes = require('./src/routes')
 app.get('*', function(req, res) {

  ReactRouter.match({
    routes: routes,
    location: req.url
  }, function(err, redirect, props) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err.message)
    }
    else if (redirect) {
      res.redirect(302, redirect.pathname + redirect.search)
    }
    else if (props) {
      var markup = renderToString(React.createElement(ReactRouter.RouterContext, props, null))
      res.render('index', { markup: markup })        
    }
    else {
      res.sendStatus(404)
    }
  })
})
```

I am basically matching location to routes using react-router.match() fucntion. I searched a lot in internet and I still can't find the replacement of .match() function in react-router v4. Can anybody please tell me how can I convert my code above to support react-router v4?

```
./src/routes.js
module.exports = <Route path="/" component={App}>
  <IndexRoute component={Top}/>
  <Route path="first" component={First}/>
  <Route path="second" component={Second}/>
  <Route path="test" component={Test}/>
  <Route path="ask" component={Ask}/>  
  </Route>
```

Comment: react-router-v4 has matchPath from react-router-dom which you can use

Comment: Adding my routes(routes.js) file also.

Comment: v4 doesn't support IndexRoute or Route component with children